How can I filter users by group in Statamic using a query scope?
In my Statamic assets blueprint, I have a users field that I want to limit to photographers only. All my users that are photographers have been placed in the user group photographers, and according to the Statamic docs, I can filter these users using a query scope.

For example, here is a photographer:
name: 'Dave Johnson'
groups:
  - photographers
id: 1231u239021313-3218931230123-321893


And here is a hypothetical query scope:
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Statamic\Query\Scopes\Scope;

class PhotographerScope extends Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope.
     *
     * @param  \Statamic\Query\Builder  $query
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply($query, $values)
    {
        // $query->whereJsonContains('groups', 'photographers');
        // some sort of query here to only select photographers?
    }
}

How would I complete this query to only select users who have the photographer value in the groups array?

Apparently, one can check sub-fields like this:
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Statamic\Query\Scopes\Scope;

class PhotographerScope extends Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope.
     *
     * @param  \Statamic\Query\Builder  $query
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply($query, $values)
    {

        $query->where('groups->photographers', true);
    }
}

News to me. Hope this helps someone.
